# Missing ) after argument list in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm a complete jQuery noob. I'm grabbing button_types and and div variables but this is giving me the error:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      $('div [button_type="'type'"]').addClass('active');
      $('div [image-var="'image'"]').addClass('active');
    });
    </script>
```

I've tried putting the ) in a multitude of locations but I'm guessing there's a bigger issue with my syntax that's causing this.

Probably an easy solution for someone that knows jQuery.

Comment: So yeah. All comments have noted that I didn't throw in concatenation. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Select one as accepted. I'm inclined to suggest T. Piscaglia to help get up that sweet site rep. :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qyfo59kr/  I'm not sure if this is limited to ES6 or what, but you can also use, I think it's called, string interpolation.  Edit: template literals, and yah, it's ES6, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @Taplar yeah, that's ES6 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829275/what-is-variable-in-javascript - pretty cool though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing + when concatenating.  Should be

```
$(function(){
      $('div [button_type="' + type + '"]').addClass('active');
      $('div [image-var="' + image +'"]').addClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should probably check the earlier answers first :)

Comment: When I was typing my answer, there was no answers yet.  Those came in as I was typing up my answer.

Comment: I'm just playin'. Enjoy your new found site rep!

Comment: Thanks.  Been a member for years.  Figured it was time for me to finally start contributing.  Also, wanted enough rep to be able to up vote :P

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the `+` signs with your variables:

```
$('div [button_type="' + type + '"]').addClass('active');
$('div [image-var="' + image + '"]').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div [button_type="'type'"]')
```

As soon as the parser hits the `'` before type, it terminates the string.  But then you have it followed by more text which is invalid syntax.  It's not entirely clear if you meant type to be a variable or not, but if so, it would look like

```
$('div [button_type="'+ type +'"]')
```